# test all the views of fragment using assertNotNull() method of JUnit

Tags: android

I want to test all the views of fragment using `assertNotNull()` method of `JUnit`, for that i have used `fragmentobject.getView()` but it is not working, i think fragments are getting loaded at the time of calling `fragmentobject.getView()` and i used timer and thread to let the fragment load even i couldn't get the view. Is there any other way to get fragment's view in JUnit test-case, is it possible to control the flow of `JUnit` by using threads and timers.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
     myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mainFragmentManager.addLaunchMainmenu();
                    /*mainFragmentMAnager is fragmentactivity object 
                    and addLaunchMainMenu() adds fragment */
            Log.d("LaunchMenuTest"," In side timer loop");
                            view = launchmainmenu.getView();
            }
    },60000);
```

mainFragmentManager is the fragmentactivity object and addLauchMainmenu() adds fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out this [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) on UI Testing in Android.

You can create a test class that extends from `UiAutomatorTestCase` and navigate through the UI. The code below simulates a user opening your application by going from the Home screen -> Apps Menu -> Clicking your app.

```
public class TestClass extends UiAutomatorTestCase {   

  public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

    // Simulate a short press on the HOME button.
    getUiDevice().pressHome();

    // We’re now in the home screen. Next, we want to simulate 
    // a user bringing up the All Apps screen.
    // If you use the uiautomatorviewer tool to capture a snapshot 
    // of the Home screen, notice that the All Apps button’s 
    // content-description property has the value “Apps”.  We can 
    // use this property to create a UiSelector to find the button. 
    UiObject allAppsButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector()
       .description("Apps"));

    // Simulate a click to bring up the All Apps screen.
    allAppsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    // In the All Apps screen, the Settings app is located in 
    // the Apps tab. To simulate the user bringing up the Apps tab,
    // we create a UiSelector to find a tab with the text 
    // label “Apps”.
    UiObject appsTab = new UiObject(new UiSelector()
       .text("Apps"));

    // Simulate a click to enter the Apps tab.
    appsTab.click();

    // Next, in the apps tabs, we can simulate a user swiping until
    // they come to the Settings app icon.  Since the container view 
    // is scrollable, we can use a UiScrollable object.
    UiScrollable appViews = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()
       .scrollable(true));

    // Set the swiping mode to horizontal (the default is vertical)
    appViews.setAsHorizontalList();

    // Create a UiSelector to find the Settings app and simulate      
    // a user click to launch the app. 
    UiObject yourApp = appViews.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
       .className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), 
       "YOUR_APP_NAME");
    yourApp.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    //This is where you can put your wait to wait for the activity
    //to load the fragment

    // Validate that the package name is the expected one
    UiObject fragmentObject = new UiObject(new UiSelector()
       .resourceId(R.layout.fragment/*the layout id of your fragment*/));
    assertTrue("Fragment not loaded", 
       fragmentObject.exists());   
  }   
}
```

Comment: sorry, my testing project doesn't support uiautomatortool. I should write them in complete JUnit.